# Share azure pipeline task 'env' across multiple tasks

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have 2 pipelines that call code from the same repository. 1 pipeline calls console applications and the other pipeline calls automation tests.

Both tasks require the same `env` to be set. Right now my yamls look like this:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run Tests
  env:
    env.var.1: $(var1)
    env.var.2: $(var2)
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '$(project)'
    publishTestResults: true
```

```yaml
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Run Console Application
  env:
    env.var.1: $(var1)
    env.var.2: $(var2)
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(workingDir)'
    script: './$(appToRun)'
    failOnStderr: true
```

Is there any way I can use a variable to store all environment variables or a task to set them before these run? My actual tasks have about 20 environment variables that need to be set.